# Password strength analyzer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, passwords

I am working with ruby on rails web application and I am trying to find the **best password strength analyzer** to validate the secure password for users when they are register. I have found some JQuery or Ajax plugins but I am not sure which one will be the best. Do you have any recommendation for me?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this gem: https://github.com/fnando/password_strength

Includes ActiveRecord support

Also you can use it in BackEnd (rails) or FrontEnd (javascript)